# hmailserver error- the connection to the database is not available

Tags: hmail-server

Dear Sir i try to make webmail server in my home pc.
so i download and install the hmailserver.
but when i try to connect it .
it has eror that "the connection to the database is not available"

and when i see the log file it has below error.
plz help me

```
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:00:58.431"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:00:59.675"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:00.185"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:00.712"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:01.228"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:01.611"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:01.786"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:01.929"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:02.230"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:02.387"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
"ERROR" 2920    "2013-10-02 01:01:03.422"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5094, Source: MySQLInterface::Load, Description: Error:[nl]The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.[nl]hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.[nl]The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.[nl]Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `libmysql.dll` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\` directory.  If you've installed WAMP, you can get a copy of this .dll from the `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.x.x\lib` folder.

Answer (score 6):

if you have a 64bit MySql server installed, using hmailserver, you will have to search LibMySQL.dll  and download 32bit file. be warned to avoid error.

Comment: Download mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip (source: http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip) and it works!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/
2. Download **Windows (x86, 32-bit), ZIP Archive**
3. Extract the downloaded folder
4. Copy the libmysql.dll file from (extracted folder)\mysql-connector-c-6.1.10-win32\lib\libmysql.dll into C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin
5. Right click the libmysql.dll file and click Properties
6. If there is an 'Unblock' checkbox down the bottom of the 'General' tab, check that and click OK
7. Restart/continue with the hmailserver installation

Answer (score 0):

If you already have file **libmysql.dll** in its place and having the same error then

1. Go to start and search for hmailserver data base setup.
2. configure it as you setup during your installtion but insure to
           choose.

   - select a new hmailserver default database (to choose the database you
     have already created)
   - Select default server type- Microsoft SQL Server/MySQL/PostgreSQL
     (Whichever you configured during installtion)
   - Next Put your database server name/ Port ,Database name(Should be
     exactly the same that you have created at the time of
     installation,you can check it by going to your databases in my case
     phpmyadmin) and click next next you should be able to connect.