# hMailserver for localhost error

Tags: email, xampp, localhost, ini, hmail-server

I'm trying to get a mail server on XAMPP and I'm stuck.

I've manually copied libmysql.dll from C:\xampp\mysql\lib to C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll but i'm still getting Error. help please with installation ?

Error:
The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.
hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.
The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll

Could someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hmailserver error- the connection to the database is not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134135/hmailserver-error-the-connection-to-the-database-is-not-available)

Comment: This could be a solution – https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31319